# iText7 reading out lines in a wrong order

Tags: c#, itext7

Im trying to read out an pdf document table but im facing an issue.

If i open the PDF regularly
It shows as:

```
item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item
item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item
item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item
```

[Reference](https://prnt.sc/qq56df)

I convert a PDF using:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    result.AppendLine("INFO_START_PAGE");
    string output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(i));
    /*Note, in the GetTextFromPage i replaced the method to output [tab] instead of a regular space on 
    big spaces*/
    foreach(string data in output.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n", "×").Split('×'))
    {
        result.AppendLine(data.Trim().Replace("   ", "[tab]"));
    }

    result.AppendLine("INFO_END_PAGE");
}

pdfDoc.Close();
return result.ToString();
```

When i try to read this out using Pdf to Text convertion in some cases it reads as:

```
item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item
item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]
item[tab]item
item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item[tab]item
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. Most likely there is a small change in vertical position in the PDF where the extracted text has the extra line break.

Comment: Hi @mkl from my view it looks like there isn't but it might be like 1 pixel. I uploaded the file here (https://mega.nz/#!kEg2DAgD!N_lL8lcbU03fAJVGqcS5MJi4WkRvO3wCb9ID6Covmdk) i did had to filter out confidential data.

Comment: For the vertical position, you should examine the page content stream, not look at the rendered page.

Comment: Welcome to the hell this is. Lucky you, mkl will probably throw you some light out. Rotation, size, cropbox, UserUnit, ITextExtractionStrategy... god no. In a nutshell: what you see is not what you get!

Comment: Yeah its all quite complicated i indeed hope @mkl can shed some light to this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: screenshot provided by the OP]

is extracted as

```
Artikelnr. Omschrijving Aantal
Per stuk Kosten
VERHUUR L. GELEVERDE ARBEID PDC 8 € 43,70 € 349,60
VERHUUR O. GELEVERDE ARBEID PDC 3 € 60,95 € 182,85
VERHUUR L.L. GELEVERDE ARBEID EM 24
€ 32,20 € 772,80
```

## First off, why does it happen

As conjectured in the comments to the question, there indeed is a small vertical step, in all rows the first three columns are set at the same vertical position and the vertical position of the last two columns differs slightly,

```
    Row       First columns y   Last columns y
Heading row               536          535.893
First row                 516          516.229
Second row                495          495.478
Third row                 475          474.788
```

One recognizes in particular that the rows broken by text extraction are those in which the pre-decimal point digits of the y positions differ (536 vs 535, 475 vs 474) while those with equal pre-decimal point digits are not broken.

The reason for this is that the class `TextChunkLocationDefaultImp` (which by default is used to store text chunk locations and methods to compare such locations) stores the y position of a chunk (actually an abstraction of it also working for text not written horizontally) in an integer variable (`private readonly int distPerpendicular`) and in the test method `SameLine` requires equality of the `distPerpendicular` values.

```c#
namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener {
    internal class TextChunkLocationDefaultImp : ITextChunkLocation {
        ...
        /// <summary>Perpendicular distance to the orientation unit vector (i.e. the Y position in an unrotated coordinate system).
        ///     </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Perpendicular distance to the orientation unit vector (i.e. the Y position in an unrotated coordinate system).
        /// We round to the nearest integer to handle the fuzziness of comparing floats.
        /// </remarks>
        private readonly int distPerpendicular;
        ...
        /// <param name="as">the location to compare to</param>
        /// <returns>true is this location is on the the same line as the other</returns>
        public virtual bool SameLine(ITextChunkLocation @as) {
            ...
            float distPerpendicularDiff = DistPerpendicular() - @as.DistPerpendicular();
            if (distPerpendicularDiff == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

*(Actually `SameLine` further down allows a small deviation if one of the compared text chunks has a zero length. Apparently chunks with zero length sometimes are used for diacritical marks, and such marks sometimes are applied at different heights. This is of no concern in your example file, though.)*

## How to fix it

As we've seen above, the problem is due to the behavior of `TextChunkLocationDefaultImp.SameLine`. Thus, we have to change this behavior. Usually, though, we don't want to change the code of the iText classes themselves.

Fortunately, the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` has a constructor that allows to inject an `ITextChunkLocationStrategy` implementation, i.e. a factory object for `ITextChunkLocation` instances.

Thus, for our task we have to write an alternative `ITextChunkLocation` implementation which is not so strict, and an `ITextChunkLocationStrategy` implementation that generates instances of our `ITextChunkLocation` implementation.

Unfortunately, though, `TextChunkLocationDefaultImp` is `internal` to iText and has numerous private variables. Thus, we cannot simply derive our implementation from it but have to copy and paste it as a whole and apply our changes to that copy.

Thus,

```c#
class LaxTextChunkLocationStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocationStrategy
{
    public LaxTextChunkLocationStrategy()
    {
    }

    public virtual ITextChunkLocation CreateLocation(TextRenderInfo renderInfo, LineSegment baseline)
    {
        return new TextChunkLocationLaxImp(baseline.GetStartPoint(), baseline.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth());
    }
}

class TextChunkLocationLaxImp : ITextChunkLocation
{
    private const float DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION = 2;
    private readonly Vector startLocation;
    private readonly Vector endLocation;
    private readonly Vector orientationVector;
    private readonly int orientationMagnitude;
    private readonly int distPerpendicular;
    private readonly float distParallelStart;
    private readonly float distParallelEnd;
    private readonly float charSpaceWidth;

    public TextChunkLocationLaxImp(Vector startLocation, Vector endLocation, float charSpaceWidth)
    {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
        this.charSpaceWidth = charSpaceWidth;
        Vector oVector = endLocation.Subtract(startLocation);
        if (oVector.Length() == 0)
        {
            oVector = new Vector(1, 0, 0);
        }
        orientationVector = oVector.Normalize();
        orientationMagnitude = (int)(Math.Atan2(orientationVector.Get(Vector.I2), orientationVector.Get(Vector.I1)) * 1000);
        Vector origin = new Vector(0, 0, 1);
        distPerpendicular = (int)(startLocation.Subtract(origin)).Cross(orientationVector).Get(Vector.I3);
        distParallelStart = orientationVector.Dot(startLocation);
        distParallelEnd = orientationVector.Dot(endLocation);
    }

    public virtual int OrientationMagnitude()
    {
        return orientationMagnitude;
    }

    public virtual int DistPerpendicular()
    {
        return distPerpendicular;
    }

    public virtual float DistParallelStart()
    {
        return distParallelStart;
    }

    public virtual float DistParallelEnd()
    {
        return distParallelEnd;
    }

    public virtual Vector GetStartLocation()
    {
        return startLocation;
    }

    public virtual Vector GetEndLocation()
    {
        return endLocation;
    }

    public virtual float GetCharSpaceWidth()
    {
        return charSpaceWidth;
    }

    public virtual bool SameLine(ITextChunkLocation @as)
    {
        if (OrientationMagnitude() != @as.OrientationMagnitude())
        {
            return false;
        }
        int distPerpendicularDiff = DistPerpendicular() - @as.DistPerpendicular();
        if (Math.Abs(distPerpendicularDiff) < 2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        LineSegment mySegment = new LineSegment(startLocation, endLocation);
        LineSegment otherSegment = new LineSegment(@as.GetStartLocation(), @as.GetEndLocation());
        return Math.Abs(distPerpendicularDiff) <= DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION && (mySegment.GetLength() == 0 || otherSegment.GetLength() == 0);
    }

    public virtual float DistanceFromEndOf(ITextChunkLocation other)
    {
        return DistParallelStart() - other.DistParallelEnd();
    }

    public virtual bool IsAtWordBoundary(ITextChunkLocation previous)
    {
        if (startLocation.Equals(endLocation) || previous.GetEndLocation().Equals(previous.GetStartLocation()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        float dist = DistanceFromEndOf(previous);
        if (dist < 0)
        {
            dist = previous.DistanceFromEndOf(this);
            //The situation when the chunks intersect. We don't need to add space in this case
            if (dist < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dist > GetCharSpaceWidth() / 2.0f;
    }

    internal static bool ContainsMark(ITextChunkLocation baseLocation, ITextChunkLocation markLocation)
    {
        return baseLocation.GetStartLocation().Get(Vector.I1) <= markLocation.GetStartLocation().Get(Vector.I1) &&
             baseLocation.GetEndLocation().Get(Vector.I1) >= markLocation.GetEndLocation().Get(Vector.I1) && Math.
            Abs(baseLocation.DistPerpendicular() - markLocation.DistPerpendicular()) <= DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION;
    }
}
```

Now to make your code use these classes, replace

```c#
string output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(i));
```

by

```c#
LocationTextExtractionStrategy laxStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(new LaxTextChunkLocationStrategy());
string output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(i), laxStrategy);
```

and the text extraction result becomes

```
Artikelnr. Omschrijving Aantal Per stuk Kosten
VERHUUR L. GELEVERDE ARBEID PDC 8 € 43,70 € 349,60
VERHUUR O. GELEVERDE ARBEID PDC 3 € 60,95 € 182,85
VERHUUR L.L. GELEVERDE ARBEID EM 24 € 32,20 € 772,80
```

as was desired.

## Additional questions

#### How to examine the pdf to know the exact locations of the rows

In a comment you asked

> May i ask how you exemined the pdf to know the exact locations of the rows?

I inspected the page using [iText RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/rups):

[image: screenshot RUPS]

In the contents of the stream selected in the screen shot I found:

```
q
...
q
1 0 0 1 60 536 cm
BT
8 0 0 8 0 0 Tm
/F3 1 Tf
(Artikelnr) Tj
8 0 0 8 31.84 0 Tm
(.) Tj
ET
Q
Q
q
...
q
1 0 0 1 147 536 cm
BT
8 0 0 8 0 0 Tm
/F3 1 Tf
(Omschrijving) Tj
ET
Q
Q
q
...
q
1 0 0 1 370 536 cm
BT
8 0 0 8 0 0 Tm
/F3 1 Tf
(Aantal) Tj
ET
Q
Q
q
...
q
1 0 0 1 433.404 535.893 cm
BT
8 0 0 8 0 0 Tm
/F3 1 Tf
(Per stuk) Tj
ET
Q
Q
q
...
q
1 0 0 1 504.878 535.893 cm
BT
8 0 0 8 0 0 Tm
/F3 1 Tf
(Kosten) Tj
ET
Q
Q
```

Before the first three headings you see

```
1 0 0 1 XXX 536 cm
```

while before the last two headings you see

```
1 0 0 1 XXX 535.893 cm
```

As the text matrix always is set with `8 0 0 8 XXX 0 Tm` to have no translation part along the y axis, the **cm** instructions above set the coordinate system so that text is drawn at y position 536 or 535.893 respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answear, this worked perfect!
May i ask how you exemined the pdf to know the exact locations of the rows?

Comment: @thekguy *"May i ask how you exemined the pdf to know the exact locations of the rows?"* - See the new section "How to examine the pdf to know the exact locations of the rows" I edited into the answer.

Comment: Bless you and all who follow in your line.  This just saved me hours and hours of headache.

Comment: Whenever I try to create the LaxTextChunkLocationStrategy I get an exception saying something about a modified collection: `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Error al realizar una enumeración por una colección: Colección 
modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Colección 
modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración.
en System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()`. Since I'm using this code in a powershell script. I can't debug CSharp code. Any ideas about what is going on?

Comment: @elysch Please make this a question in its own right and provide all information necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you before. The problem was a terrible handle of error messages. The real problem was that powersell was reporting `ADVERTENCIA: El tipo generado no es público.` That means something like `Warning: the generated type is not public`. Just added the "public" word before the class definition and got working.

Comment: Great that it resolved so easily!

Comment: Hello again. I added a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72507825/2796922). In case you can review it