# iText7 reading out lines in a wrong order (2)

Tags: itext7

I'm using iText 7.2.2. I'm trying to extract text from some PDFs that come from a scan process.

I have a pdf that where processed using [ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in order to add a "OCR-ed" text layer.

The following image shows the original text (before OCR)
[image]

When I extract the text, I get newlines, many spaces (trimmed here) and the words are in the wrong order.
The code:

```
"NAME  : [$($name)]"
```

Produces:

```
NAME  : [NARANJAS
HERNANDEZ
C.V.
S.A. DE]
```

It's in the wrong order, so I can't simply join the lines.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825023/2796922) post that sounds promising, but my case ended up being a little different. Implementing what it proposes, results in the following:

```
NAME  : [NARANJAS HERNANDEZ C.V.
S.A. DE]
```

The following code comes from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825023/2796922) post:

```
  public virtual bool SameLine(ITextChunkLocation @as)
  {
//      Console.WriteLine("OrientationMagnitude: " + OrientationMagnitude() + ", as.OrientationMagnitude: " + @as.OrientationMagnitude());
      if (OrientationMagnitude() != @as.OrientationMagnitude())
      {
          return false;
      }
      int distPerpendicularDiff = DistPerpendicular() - @as.DistPerpendicular();
      if (Math.Abs(distPerpendicularDiff) < 5)
      {
          return true;
      }
      LineSegment mySegment = new LineSegment(startLocation, endLocation);
      LineSegment otherSegment = new LineSegment(@as.GetStartLocation(), @as.GetEndLocation());
      return Math.Abs(distPerpendicularDiff) <= DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION && (mySegment.GetLength() == 0 || otherSegment.GetLength() == 0);
  }
```

The commented line produces the following, when not commented, of course :)

```
OrientationMagnitude: 6, as.OrientationMagnitude: 0
OrientationMagnitude: 6, as.OrientationMagnitude: 6
OrientationMagnitude: 6, as.OrientationMagnitude: 6
OrientationMagnitude: 7, as.OrientationMagnitude: 6
OrientationMagnitude: 7, as.OrientationMagnitude: 7
NOMBRE  : [NARANJAS HERNANDEZ C.V.
S.A. DE]
```

This is as far as I could go.

The rups executable shows:

[image]

Any pointers on how to fix this, would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in your console printouts, the orientation value is different for the different text chunks, which results in `SameLine` returning `false` and text extraction consequentially extracting differently oriented text as different text lines.

Thus, I'd try making the orientation comparison a bit lax just like the distPerpendicular comparison already has been made more lax.

For example, in `SameLine` replace

```cs
if (OrientationMagnitude() != @as.OrientationMagnitude())
```

by

```cs
int orientationMagnitudeDiff = OrientationMagnitude() - @as.OrientationMagnitude();
if (Math.Abs(orientationMagnitudeDiff) > 3)
```

(you might want to experiment and change the value '3' a bit).

Comment: I changed the code like this: `int orientationMagnitudeDiff = OrientationMagnitude() - @as.OrientationMagnitude(); if (Math.Abs(orientationMagnitudeDiff) > 6) { return false; }` and now it puts all in the same line, but it's still in the wrong order: `NOMBRE  : [NARANJAS HERNANDEZ C.V. S.A. DE]` . It should be `S.A. DE C.V.]` at the end. Any ideas?

Comment: Hhmmm, the wrong order is due to the text chunks being sorted using the `DefaultTextChunkLocationComparator` which first sorts by orientation and only thereafter by distPerpendicular. That shifts the chunks with a larger orientation value to the back. Thus, it unfortunately is not that easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same line issue with the fix from the [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820361/itext7-reading-out-lines-in-a-wrong-order/59825023#59825023), but it was still in the wrong order. I used qpdf to decode the PDF, played around with the individual lines with this command, and then edited it in Notepad++.

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable --decode-level=all in.pdf decoded.pdf
```

I found that changing the height vector of the affected line by one would fix it, from

```
1 0 0 -1 19 234 Tm
```

to

```
1 0 0 -1 19 235 Tm
```

I added a little flex to the `CompareTo` function in the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and that solved the issue for me:

```
 public int CompareTo(ITextChunkLocation other)   {
        if (this == other)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int num = CompareInts(orientationMagnitude, other.OrientationMagnitude);
        if (num != 0)
        {
            return num;
        }

        var diff = Math.Abs(distPerpendicular - other.DistPerpendicular);
        if (diff > 2)
        {
            return CompareInts(distPerpendicular, other.DistPerpendicular);
        }

        return (!(distParallelStart < other.DistParallelStart)) ? 1 : (-1);
    }
```

This was using iText 7.1.15 and TextSharp 5.5.13.2

Comment: This did merge some columns for me in my document, but it was consistent so it didn't matter for my purposes. I played around with a distParallelStart comparison, but it caused more issues than it solved. I'd love to see a more comprehensive solution if anyone's got one.

Answer (score 0):

mkl Already answered for the orientation, but for the order I managed to fix it by modifying

```
public TextChunkLocationLaxImp(Vector startLocation, Vector endLocation, float charSpaceWidth)
{
   ...
   distPerpendicular = (int)(startLocation.Subtract(origin)).Cross(orientationVector).Get(Vector.I3);
   ...
}
```

to

```
public TextChunkLocationLaxImp(Vector startLocation, Vector endLocation, float charSpaceWidth)
{
   ...
   distPerpendicular = (int)(startLocation.Subtract(origin)).Cross(orientationVector).Get(Vector.I3);
   bool newV = true;
   foreach (int distP in UI.previousDistPerpendiculars)
   {
      if (Math.Abs(distPerpendicular - distP) <= DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION)
      {
          distPerpendicular = distP;
          newV = false;
      }
   }
   if (newV)
      UI.previousDistPerpendiculars.Add(distPerpendicular);
   ...
}
```

The UI.previousDistPerpendiculars is a global variable. Make sure to clear it on each new page.

Note that DIACRITAL... is the same variable as in the function we were using previously. But by changing the distPerpendicular in this function, we can group lines together.

```
if (Math.Abs(distPerpendicularDiff) < DIACRITICAL_MARKS_ALLOWED_VERTICAL_DEVIATION)
{
     return true;
}
```

This should work, with two caveats :

- If the variable is too low, it won't work as intended
- If it is too high, it will "mix rows"

You will need to manually find the best value.

This is my second post on this site, so do tell me if I didn't follow best practices.
Also I know it's a bit late, but this question and the previous one were very useful for me, so I wanted to make sure I shared what I had managed to do afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Try Docotic.Pdf instead. I was having the same issues until I switched from iText7 to Docotic.Pdf. Works great!